# How to write logic to handle arduino sensors on separate computer

Tags: arduino, hardware

The ArduinoIDE writes firmware to my Arduino UNO but I want to handle logic and code outside the microcontroller on the computer with the microcontroller strictly being a sensor and the computer handling the logic.

How can I have the computer handle the logic and listen to sensors (output data to a computer) and respond (input commands to the board)?

Is this done with serials?  How do I get started with this?

I know how to code, I just need help understanding how to get the hardware to talk to one another. Arduino to computer, computer to arduino.

For example, I have a thermal sensor on the board, how can I have bi-directional communication where the output of temperature would go to a program on my computer and respond to the board to turn on an LED or other command based on statements on the computer.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [tutorial](http://arduino.cc/en/tutorial/Graph#.UwT_H_ldW0g) on arduino.cc how to read a sensor on arduino en display the values in processing.

There is also a [tutorial](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/PhysicalPixel#.UwT_pPldW0g) to turn on a led with a command from a pc.

If you want to do real complicated things I suggest that you take a look at [Firmata](http://firmata.org/wiki/Main_Page)